# Authoryear cite style in tex, problems using natbib in Texmaker (on mac)

Tags: natbib, texmaker, cite-package

I am trying to use natbib in my bibtex file with plainnat style. However, I experience a number of issues (however works fine in e.g. Sharelatex). Depending on my code i get the error: Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

```
documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%MATH specifications%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}%mathematical typesetting
\usepackage{mathptmx}%setter språk og matte til times roman.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Formatering%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}%set line spacing
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} %fjerner innrykk i avsnitt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%Diverse%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\newcommand{\Expect}{{\rm I\kern-.3em E}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%BIBTEX%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
%also tried \usepackage[round,year,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{a4paper}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{titlepage}

%here i have my thesis

\bibliography{Master}
\nocite{*}
\begin{doublespacing}   % Double-space the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

I have tried every possible solution suggested out there, not able to make it work any how... E.g if i delete the aux and bbl file i get: ! Misplaced alignment tab character &. and so on...

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It seems like Natbib did not support some of the bibtex references from jstor. By re-entering them all using BibDesk I had no errors and was free to use any style I wanted. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "natbib [rather: the `plainnat` style?] did not support some of the bibtex references from jstor". You didn't show any of the bibliographic entries that were giving `plainnat` problems.